# Is there an alternative to batching requests (MapHttpBatchRoute) in ASP.NET Core WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on migrating an ASP.NET WebAPI application to ASP.NET Core. In this application I'm using batch routes (as described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata/). It's quite elegant - all I need to do is to map a batch route using `config.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute`, and then just batch whatever API requests I want to from the client. However, I haven't found an alternative to this in ASP.NET Core. Does it exist, or do I need to write batch APIs myself that perform what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success using this library: https://github.com/Tornhoof/HttpBatchHandler

It works for .Net Core 3.0 and newer. The documentation isn't the best though.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks.

Do you have an example of how it's used? As you say, the documentation wasn't very impressive...

Comment: I almost got it working - however, the User.Identity doesn't seem to flow from the parent HttpContext to each individual request in the batch. Thus all the subrequests are not able to access the APIs.

I might just make my own aggregator APIs for this... since it doesn't seem like this nuget is something that's very actively maintained, so that in itself introduces some risk.

Comment: Could you use the state object as described in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Tornhoof/HttpBatchHandler/issues/14

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark yours as the answer since it probably is the closest there is currently. 

I did end up creating dedicated batch APIs though for this... feels a bit less hacky - and guess there's a reason why ASP.NET Core doesn't implement this functionality... perhaps.

Anyhow, thanks! Hopefully this can be helpful to others as well.